# Error publishing python dict to Solace using AMQP/qpid-proton

Tags: solace

Trying to run producer.py from solace-samples-amqp-qpid-proton-python with payload of python dict

```
Message(id=(self.sent+1), body={'sequence':(self.sent+1)})
```

Get following error

> Reject message: 1 Remote disposition:
>   Condition('amqp:not-implemented', 'unsupported AMQP value type:
>   TOK_MAP_START')

Get similar error when trying to send integer value in body - TOK_TYPE_INT

Does solace support only Strings over AMQP?

Answer (score 0):

Solace message brokers support amqp-value message sections containing values of types null, string, binary, symbol, or uuid. (https://docs.solace.com/Open-APIs-Protocols/AMQP/AMQP-Protocol-Conformance.htm#Sec3-2-8)

This is done in order to preserve maximum message inter-operability.

Any published message using a language specific semantic can only be consumed using the same semantic. I.e. if you publish with Python dict, you can only decode using Python dict, so if you are using a MQTT or REST consumer, it will not be able to decode the message.

The best option is to use a cross-language serialization library, which will make it easier for future expansions. For example, you might decide to add an REST consumer to in future, which can decode the data using the cross-language serialization library.